# Calculated column in SharePoint list - Conditional formula for finding difference

Tags: list, calculated-column-formula, calculated-column

I am working on creating a leave tracker list. For that, I have added a column for Leave Type with 4 choices with 1 choice being company off.

I want to add another column that says => Comp offs left which should calculate the difference between the total number of comp off lefts, i.e. 12-Number of days(s) leave requested for if the leave type is comp off.

I tried to use simple if statement but getting the value as No. I tried using int function and that too does not work.

```
=IF([Leave Type]="Company off (In lieu of)",12-int([Number of day(s)]))
```

Comment: What is the data type of your "Number of day(s)" column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
=IF([Leave Type]="Company off (In lieu of)", 12 - VALUE([Number of day(s)]), 0)
```

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Return your calculated field as **Number**.

**official documentation**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)).
2. [VALUE function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/value-function-1fc46e51-4a25-4ba0-bce2-512dd5d4d872)

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried using this formula but the values returns 0 all the time and not the difference. And I did try using semicolon as well but that resulted in syntax error.

Comment: The logic behind the formula is: If Leave Type column is equal to "Company off (In lieu of)" then get `12 - Number of days` else it will return 0. As you are getting 0 everytime, I will suggest you to create a new list item which will have Leave Type="Company off (In lieu of)".

Comment: Also check you are passing the correct choice value (Company off (In lieu of)) in formula. it is case-sensitive and it should be exactly same as it is given in column settings.

Comment: Thank you. It works now. I copy-pasted the exact value and then tried.

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you.

Comment: Hello @ganesh How can I make sure that the number of comp off left is not always subtracted from 12, i.e. first time when a user enters a comp off, it should get subtracted from 12, the next time, it should get subtracted from the comp off left and not from 12.

Comment: You need to store the comp off days left in another column in list. then you can use that column here in formula instead of 12.